# Pipeline GridSearchCV, corresponding parameters in different steps

Tags: python, pipeline, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am trying to do some hyper-parameter tuning in my pipeline and have the following setup:

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = create_model, epochs = 5)  
pipeline = Pipeline(steps =[('Tokenizepadder', TokenizePadding()),
                          ('NN', model)] )
```

Where I have a variable 'maxlen' in both the Tokenizepadder and my Neural Network (for the Neural Network it is called max_length, I was afraid naming them the same would cause errors later in the code). When I try to perform a grid search, I am struggling to have these values correspond. If I perform grid search for these values seperately, they won't mach and there will be a problem with the input data not matching the neural network.

In short I would like to do something like:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps =[('Tokenizepadder', TokenizePadding()),
                           ('NN', KerasClassifier(build_fn = create_model, epochs = 5, max_length = pipeline.get_params()['Tokenizepadder__maxlen']))] )
```

So that when I am performing a grid search for the parameter 'Tokenizepadder__maxlen', it will change the value 'NN__max_length' to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can change your classifier and tokenizer, to pass around `max_len` parameter. Then, only grid search with tokenizer `max_len` parameter.
Not the cleanest way, but might do.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, EstimatorMixin
class TokeinizePadding(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, max_len, ...):
        self.max_len = max_len
        ...

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        ...
        return self
   
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        data = ... # your stuff
        return {"array": data, "max_len": self.max_len}
 

class KerasClassifier(...):
    ...
    def fit(data, y):
        self.max_len = data["max_len"]
        self.build_model()
        X = data["array"]
        ... # your stuff
```